# PHP middleware not called in correct order

Tags: php, middleware

Implementing middleware for a side-project API but the middleware is not being called in the correct order.  The correct order should print:
AUTH
[ControllerMethod]
TOKEN

But currently it's printing the TOKEN middleware first with a result of:
AUTH
TOKEN
[ControllerMethod]

I can't figure out why the TokenMiddleware handle function is being called first.

UPDATE:  We have narrowed down the issue to the Router::dispatch() method.  For some reason, call_user_func_array executes before my TokenMiddleware class does.

Code is below:

**Kernel.php**

```
public function handle($request)
{
    if ($routePackage = $this->router->find($request)) {
        $controller_name = $routePackage['route']->action['controller'];
        $controller = $this->controllerCollection->find($controller_name);

        if ($controller === null) {
            $fqcn = "\\app\\controllers\\".$controller_name;
            $controller = new $fqcn();
            $this->controllerCollection->add($controller_name, $controller);
        }

        return (new Pipeline)
                ->send($request)
                ->through($controller->getMiddleware())
                ->then($this->dispatchToRouter());
    }
}

private function dispatchToRouter()
{
    return function ($request)
    {
        return $this->router->dispatch($request);
    };
}
```

**Pipeline.php**

```
class Pipeline
{
    private $pipes = [];

    private $object;

    private $method = 'handle';

    public function send($object)
    {
        $this->object = $object;

        return $this;
    }

    public function through($pipes)
    {
        $this->pipes = array_merge($this->pipes, $pipes); 
        return $this;
    }

    public function then(Closure $core)
    {
        $coreFunction = $this->createCoreFunction($core);

        $pipes = array_reverse($this->pipes);

        $completePipeline = array_reduce($pipes, function($nextPipe, $pipe)
        {
            return $this->createPipe($nextPipe, $pipe);
        }, $coreFunction);

        return $completePipeline();
    }

    private function createCoreFunction(Closure $core)
    {
        return function() use ($core)
        {
            return call_user_func($core, $this->object);
        };
    }

    private function createPipe($nextPipe, $pipe)
    {
        #print_r($nextPipe);
        #echo "==============================================";
        #print_r($pipe);
        return function () use ($nextPipe, $pipe)
        {
            return call_user_func_array([$pipe, $this->method], [$this->object, $nextPipe]);
        };
    }
}
```

**Router.php**

```
class Router
{
    private $controllerCollection;

    public function __construct($controllerCollection = null)
    {
        $this->controllerCollection = $controllerCollection;
        $this->routeCollection = new RouteCollection();
    }

    public function find($request)
    {
        return $this->routeCollection->find($request);
    }

    public function dispatch($request)
    {
        print_r($request);
        if ($routePackage = $this->find($request)) {
            $controller_name = $routePackage['route']->action['controller'];
            $controller = $this->controllerCollection->find($controller_name);

            // Inject request if needed -- TODO: MOVE THIS
           # $reflection_method = new \ReflectionMethod($controller, $routePackage['route']->action['method']);
            #$args = $reflection_method->getParameters();

           # for ($i = 0; $i < count($args); $i++) {
            #    $class = $args[$i]->getClass();

            #    if ($class) {
            #        if ($class->getName() === 'framework\http\Request') {
             #           if ($routePackage['params']) {
             #               array_splice($routePackage['params'], $i, 0, array($request));   
             #           } else {
                            $routePackage['params'] = [$request];
            #            }

            #            break;
            #        }
            #    }     
            #}

            return call_user_func_array([$controller, $routePackage['route']->action['method']], $routePackage['params']);  // PROBLEM LIES HERE: THIS IS BEING CALLED BEFORE MIDDLEWARE
            #return $controller->call($routePackage['route']->action['method'], $routePackage['params']);
        }
    }
}
```

**AuthMiddleware.php**

```
class AuthMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        echo "AUTH";

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**TokenMiddleware.php**

```
class TokenMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        echo "TOKEN";

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to show how you register the middlewares. The order is defined by `$this->pipes = array_merge($this->pipes, $pipes)` and  `$pipes = array_reverse($this->pipes);`

Comment: Hmm I don't think that matters. I will post the code when I can. They get added in the Controller's constructor. This implementation is similar to Laravel's  and, therefore, should be dictated by how the middleware handles the next closure. See my AuthMiddleware and TokenMiddleware handle methods and notice the difference.

Comment: ah, indeed, I did't notice the token is executed after the controller. Are you saying that if you die in auth middleware, the token middleware still echoes "TOKEN"?

Comment: @AlexBlex, I haven't gotten to that logic yet.  If you fail in Auth you will eventually die and not execute further.  However, right now, I'm just trying to output in the correct order to ensure that the methods/closures are being called in the correct order: they are not.

Comment: hard to believe. Can you provide a stripped-down reproducible example?

Comment: nm, did it myself:  https://repl.it/J7VZ echoes `AUTH [ControllerMethod] TOKEN`

Comment: Wow, that's odd.  So really the only thing you changed is the Closure you have being sent to Pipeline::then()

Comment: Well, you never exposed what `dispatchToRouter` is, but I assume it returns  a Closure, otherwise it wouldn't match type-hint for `Pipeline::then` function.

Comment: @AlexBlex Please see Kernel.php above.  I added it below the handle() function.

Comment: and? It confirms that `dispatchToRouter` returns a Closure, thanks.  I don't see how it changes anything. The code snippets in the question are correct. Suggest the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have added the Router class.  In the dispatch() method I make a call to call_user_func_array().  That is executing before my TokenMiddleware gets a chance.

Comment: You sure? It doesn't here https://repl.it/J7VZ/1 Sorry man, debug over Stackoverflow is a way to nowhere. Try to do the same yourself - add 1 bit at a time until you get the reproducible error. When you localise the problem you can fix it. Otherwise you are chasing ghosts.